# Is there an Android app with a calendar and the ability to drag and resize like toggl but that doesn't have a time-limitation in what it shows?

Tags: calendar, time-management

Is there an android calendar app with the ability to drag and resize like toggl calendar but that doesn't have limitations of eg 2 weeks in what it shows?

Toggl has the feature, but they keep putting limitations on their app in terms of how far you can go back. e.g. they used to be limited to only show two weeks back, and now they extended it to 3 months back.  But still limited there. Even though they store info from further back

And not Google calendar.. Google calendar used to be ok for me because it has dragging to draw tasks on, and it let me view one calendar at a time. But I don't like the change they made of having calendars enabled and disabled with checkboxes. Unless Google were to have profiles where each profile had particular things checked. I also don't like the change they made where they hide the calendar while you enter a task name.  I'm looking for calendars other than google calendar that allow what i'm talking about. I use Google Calendar as my main calendar. But a calendar with a different account for time tracking.     I used to use Google Calendar with two calendars one for time tracking and one for events. But then they changed it. So I need a different app to google calendar.

Toggl would be perfect, and the calendar is a bit like google calendar app used to be in that when you type a task name in it doesn't hide the whole calendar.. But I can't find any other app like Toggl or google calendar app, that lets you drag an item on the calendar to set the time period of it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer.

But, you can sync the data from Toggl to any one of your google account calendars. And they can go back. So perhaps the limit there isn't that much of an issue.

There is 24me which doesn't seem to go back befor 2018, and isn't as nice as toggl. e.g. toggl you can add an event while still looking at the calendar.

Google is the ugliest one in that with google it moves to a different screen to add the task and then won't let you drag to resize while looking at the calendar. But it's good for viewing the calendar in the past

Toggl is then good for seeing you you spend your time and what you are doing on the calendar